# "...Проповедь новой религии была запрещена"? "Последнее гонение от язычников прошло во времена..."?

Tags: стилистика

> **Последнее гонение от язычников прошло во времена правления императора Юлиана II** (Отступника, 331–363). Император Юлиан,
>   неоплатоник, любимец войск и племянник Константина Великого,
>   стремился восстановить язычество. Он не признавал христианства, но был
>   вынужден заимствовать многие элементы нового богослужения и
>   устройство института церкви для реставрации старой религии. Впрочем,
>   ему стало довольно быстро понятно, что процесс христианизации давно
>   окончен и обратное движение уже невозможно. Даже если ему подыгрывали
>   в столице, в Антиохии (ныне Сирии), где население было христианским,
>   решения императора вызывали глухое противостояние. Тем не менее
>   **проповедь новой религии была запрещена**, и христианам не разрешалось занимать преподавательские посты.

И - как оформить Юлиана II?

*Юлиан II Отступник (331–363)?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"Проповедь религии"** в этом смысле (не как отдельная речь) я не обнаружил в словаре, но в Нацкорпусе она встречается (хотя и редко). По-моему, можно оставить ее в тексте.

И борьба с ним состоит не в **проповеди «религии»** (которая при секуляризме сама становится идолопоклонством, даже когда она облечена в христианские одежды), а в раскрытии «твари» как творения. [А. Д. Шмеман. Дневники (1973-1983)]

Для него Достоевский часто является лишь средством для **проповеди религии** воскресшей плоти, и единственное своеобразие духа Достоевского он не видит. [Н. А. Бердяев. Миросозерцание Достоевского (1923)]

А вот **"гонение от"** уж слишком сильно пахнет нафталином. Я бы заменил на "гонение со стороны". Да и "прошло" тоже из далекого прошлого (извините за тавтологию), не лучше ли сказать "произошло"?

Это необходимо не только как единственное средство для спасения России, как, государства, но в той же мере ― для снятия с себя преступного уклонения от Божией правды и восстановления такого строя, при котором Церковь не будет в прямом **гонении от государства**. [митрополит Антоний (Храповицкий). Церковность или политика? (1921)]

А ныне крайность и **гонение от турок** заставляют скитаться семейства наших фамилий, кои находятся в Австрийской империи, где поселиться не могут по причине малоземелия, сверх того ненависти к христианам, делая им разные притеснения, и претерпевая немалое время от турок, желаем остаться под короною Российской империи, ежели Сербия свободною от ига турок быть не может. [Б. Миленкович. Прошение министру внутренних дел О. П. Козодавлеву (1814)]